How to deploy spring boot application in godaddy server
Hi I have deployed spring boot application in AWS EC2. But the cost of AWS is high.
So I am trying to Use godaddy. Can we deploy the spring boot application in godaddy server.

I have no idea what godaddy server means, but if you can connect with ssh to it then you will be able to deploy apps on it.

seems to be a good starting resource for you
